# Conversion of ENVI binary files to tiff

Tags: rstudio, data-conversion, envi

I have a challenge in converting a batch of ENVI binary files(BSQ) temperature data(gotten from SAFARI 2000 AVHRR-Derived LST) to geotiff files. How can i read them and convert it to geotiff?
An example of one such file is 'afn_011-011_96.n14-LST_UL'

Comment: What is the reason for the `batch-file` tag, it does not seem related?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to provide a proper sample dataset and the corresponding meta-data that tells you the image dimensions in pixels, the data type and so on, but in principle you can do it with **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

So, using the dataset here [sample dataset](http://www.qgistutorials.com/downloads/gl-latlong-1deg-landcover.bsq.gz) and knowing the data is unsigned 8 bit and 360x180 pixels, you would run this command in Terminal (or Command Prompt if on Windows):

```
convert -size 360x180 -depth 8 gray:gl-latlong-1deg-landcover.bsq -auto-level result.tif
```

If your data is multi-band band-sequential, you may have to use:

```
convert -size 360x180 -depth 8 -interlace plane rgb:gl-latlong-1deg-landcover.bsq -auto-level result.tif
```

Or, if you cannot get that to work, you may need to extract each band separately using a byte offset and then combine them afterwards, something like:

```
convert -size 360x180        -depth 8 gray:image.bsq -auto-level red.tif
convert -size 360x180+64800  -depth 8 gray:image.bsq -auto-level green.tif
convert -size 360x180+129600 -depth 8 gray:image.bsq -auto-level blue.tif
convert red.tif green.tif blue.tif -combine RGB.tif
```

---

Note that if you install **ImageMagick** v7 or newer, the above commands change to:

```
magick -size ...
```

rather than:

```
convert -size ...
```

---

**Keywords**: ImageMagick, command-line, command line, image, image processing, satellite, ENVI, band-sequential, planar, imagery, AVHRR, convert